# disable chrome://inspect debugging in IONIC2 app

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am currently developing an Ionic2 app. I can debug the app using chrome://inspect debugging.

Is there is any way to disable this debugging in release apk of app. I am using Android studio to build signed apk for release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` there should be a `android:debuggable="true"` attribute on the `<application>` element. If you remove that and build the app, it shouldn't be debuggable anymore.

I think when you build your Android app using command `ionic build android --release` it won't add the android:debuggable property to the manifest xml.